# Настройка таймера в Linux

Tags: c++, linux

можно ли настроить программный таймер в linux 4.2.0 на время не кратное 1 мс, к примеру 55,5 мс?  Подходит ли для этого [boost::deadline_timer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html)?
P.S.Нужно для точного опроса железки.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что начать вам стоит с этого поста https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy/710#710

Comment: Плохая идея. В многозадачной среде у вас практически нет шансов получить шаг таймера меньше 10-15ms. Даже если вы скомпилируете якобы-realtime ядро.

Фактически, вы требуете от системного таймера шага в 500 микросекунд, что запредельно мелко.

Более того, через какой интерфейс вы это собрались делать?

Comment: @gbg слегка отвлечённый вопрос от мимокрокодила: а если все сторонние задачи простаивают, шансов всё равно нет?

Comment: @andreymal - В линуксе какая-нибудь-да задача все время болтается, тот же процесс, который в фоне обнуляет страницы памяти.

Более того, на современных материнках у процессора есть, грубо говоря Ring -1, где выполняется firmware, зашитая в материнку, куда он (проц) улетает для выполнения очень уж системных дел, связанных с обслуживанием электропитания или IPMI

Comment: Но есть одна задача, которая все таки как то работает - звуковая карта:)

Comment: @KoVadim так там DMA, буферы и свой тактовый генератор. Джиттер даже с ASIO составляет порядка все той же десятки миллисекунд

Comment: вот вот. поэтому берем простеньку ардуинку, и вперед с музыкой.

Comment: @KoVadim это если автору не нужно с этим периодом перемножать матрицы на десятки тысяч элементов.

Comment: их можно умножить предварительно

Comment: на уровне API linux может и до 1 наносекунды точность обеспечить... в принципе на бумаге x86 может обеспечивать 0.1 мс... IRL не стоит рассчитывать на что-то более точное, чем 1 мс и не стоит полагаться на что-то точнее 5 мс... ну и все оговорки про многозадачность, прерывания, управление памятью и т.п... через что оно реализовано в boost'е — надо смотреть хотя бы под strace'ом запустить — будет видно: если там под капотом обычные `poll`/`select`, то — гаврантированно нет,  не точнее 1мс, а если что-то linux'овое то, на бумаге может и получится, но IRL — вряд ли можно гарантировать...

Comment: Короче из всего вышеуказанного можно сделать вывод, это невозможно -)

Comment: из вышенаписанного нужно сделать вывод, что нужно писать изначальную задачу, а не то, как вы ее интерпретировали

Comment: Задача указана выше, у железки своя циклограмма с заданным аппаратным циклом, необходим способ к нему гарантированно привязаться.

Comment: @Федор что за железка, какой интерфейс - аудитории предполагается угадать. Так разговор не пойдет.

Вы топик про микроскоп и молоток прочитали? Так вот, у вас идентичная история, вы спрашиваете "Как сделать, чтобы микроскоп не разбился?", мы удивляемся, как вы умудрились его разбить.

Comment: @Федор, большиство интерфейсов, доступных в линуксе, вносят задержку порядка единиц-десятков миллисекунд, как вы привязываться собираетесь? Для точных измерений времени с таким масштабом ПК просто не подходит по архитектуре.

Comment: Посмотрите на то, как работает cyclictest из [rt-tests](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/howto/tools/rt-tests). *Гарантировать* разрешение в 500 мкс (как и любое другое; линукс - не система РВ) оно, конечно, не сможет, но статистически должно укладываться в него в более чем 99 процентов случаев :)